# Android: Save view that was added in RecyclerView with SharedPrefs

Tags: java, android

I'm adding views to a RecyclerView by clicking on a button, I want those views to be saved, preferably in SharedPrefrences how do we do this and do we need a json?

**Here's the adapter:**

```
public class SubjectsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    public Activity mcontext;

    public SubjectsAdapter(Activity context) {
        this.mcontext=context;
    }

    public void addItem(String name) {
        items.add(name);
        notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_button, parent, false);
        view.requestFocus();
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    static int i = 100;
    static int h = 1000;
    public EditText EditName;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public Button GridButton;
        private TextView ClassName;
        public SharedPreferences prefs;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            GridButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_button);
            EditName = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editName);
            ClassName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ClassName);
            prefs = mcontext.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            GridButton.setId(++i);
            GridButton.setText(prefs.getString("key", i + ""));

            EditName.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm adding views from the activity like this `adapter.addItem("something");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant' store views in the SharedPreference, but you can store the value of the textview.

```
pref = getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
ed = pref.edit();
ed.putString(prefKey2, textView.getText().toString()).commit();
```

Then you can set the stored value to the textview

```
textView.setText(pref.getString(prefKey2, ""));
```

Comment: I can store the TextView, but if the view isn't stored there will be no TextView to store

Comment: You need to store all values, and recreate all views.

Comment: what do you mean recreate all views?

Comment: Ok I can't save the views, meaning I have to use onSaveInstanceState, and the views will recreate everytime the activity starts and get the saved data?

Comment: You can store in cloud, and then retrieve all values in your app, and store all values in an ArrayList, and depending on the size of that list, recreate all views.